# Hashing same string generates different results in kernel module

Tags: c, kernel-module, cryptoapi

I am following https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/crypto/api-samples.html#code-example-for-use-of-operational-state-memory-with-shash and I have a LKM structure as such:

test.c

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include "chip.h"

#define SHA_DIGEST_SIZE 32 
#define SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE SHA_DIGEST_SIZE * 2 

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL"); 

static char ker_buf[200];

static int dev_open(struct inode *inod, struct file *fil);
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep,char *buf,size_t len,loff_t *off);
static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *flip,const char *buff,size_t len,loff_t *off);
static int dev_release(struct inode *inod,struct file *fil);

static struct file_operations fops=
{
.read=dev_read,
.write=dev_write,
.open=dev_open,
.release=dev_release,
};

static int hello_init(void){
int t=register_chrdev(90,"mydev",&fops);
if(t<0)
printk(KERN_ALERT "device registration failed.");
else
printk(KERN_ALERT "device registred\n");
return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void){
unregister_chrdev(90,"mydev");
printk(KERN_ALERT "exit");
} 

static int dev_open(struct inode *inod, struct file *fil){
printk("KERN_ALERT device opened");
return 0;
} 

static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep,char *buf,size_t len,loff_t *off){
size_t i;
unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_SIZE];
unsigned char digest_hd[SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE+2];
int hash = generate_hash(ker_buf, len, digest);

for (i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_SIZE; i++)
    sprintf(&digest_hd[i*2], "%02x", digest[i]);   

copy_to_user(buf,ker_buf,len);
return len;
}

static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *flip,const char *buf,size_t len,loff_t *off)
{  
copy_from_user(ker_buf,buf,len);
ker_buf[len]=0;
return len;
}

static int dev_release(struct inode *inod,struct file *fil){
printk("KERN_ALERT device closed\n");
return 0;
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

chip.h

```
#include <crypto/hash.h>

#ifndef MODULE_CHIP_H
#define MODULE_CHIP_H

struct shash_desc *init_sdesc(struct crypto_shash *alg);

int calc_hash(struct crypto_shash *alg, const unsigned char *data, unsigned 
int datalen,unsigned char *digest);

int generate_hash(const unsigned char *data, unsigned int datalen,unsigned char *digest);

#endif
```

chip.c

```
#include "chip.h"

struct shash_desc *init_sdesc(struct crypto_shash *alg)
{
struct shash_desc *sdesc;

sdesc = kmalloc(sizeof(*sdesc) + crypto_shash_descsize(alg), GFP_KERNEL);
if (!sdesc)
    return ERR_PTR(-ENOMEM);
sdesc->tfm = alg;

return sdesc;
}

int calc_hash(struct crypto_shash *alg,
                 const unsigned char *data, unsigned int datalen,
                 unsigned char *digest)
{
struct shash_desc *sdesc;
int ret;

sdesc = init_sdesc(alg);
if (IS_ERR(sdesc)) {
    pr_err("can't alloc sdesc\n");
    return PTR_ERR(sdesc);
}

ret = crypto_shash_digest(sdesc, data, datalen, digest);
kfree(sdesc);
return ret;
}

int generate_hash(const unsigned char *data, unsigned int datalen,
                 unsigned char *digest)
{
struct crypto_shash *alg;
char *hash_alg_name = "sha256";
int ret;

alg = crypto_alloc_shash(hash_alg_name, 0, 0);
if (IS_ERR(alg)) {
    pr_err("can't alloc alg %s\n", hash_alg_name);
    return PTR_ERR(alg);
}
ret = calc_hash(alg, data, datalen, digest);

crypto_free_shash(alg);
return ret;
}
```

Makefile

```
KVERSION := $(shell uname -r)
obj-m := test1.o
test1-objs := test.o chip.o
all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

module loads and runs as expected, my goal is to get the hashed version of the written string read back from kernel module. The values I read back are a hex string of the expected length, but not matching the correct hash of the input. What I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: The size of digest_hd is SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE+2, you write SHA_DIGEST_SIZE*2 chars into it and then copy to user the length_of_plaintext out of it. (buf is a user pointer? then you should copy from user as well?)

Comment: Four things: (1) `read` file operation handlers are not supposed to use the existing contents of the buffer, they are supposed to just overwrite the buffer. (2) `buf` is a pointer to user memory - is that what `generate_hash()` is expecting? (3) The value of `len` could be larger than than the size of the `digest_hd` array, resulting in buffer overflow. (4) Are `SHA_DIGEST_SIZE` and `SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE` correct for whatever variant of `SHA` you are using in `generate_hash()`?

Comment: test_hash function in the link is identical to my function generate_hash. buf variable is a string read from userspace and I am trying to hash it in kernelspace then send hashed string back to userspace

Comment: @servedc0ld: Assuming `dev_read` function to be registered as `.read` callback for `struct file_operations`, when this function is called, content of the memory pointed by `buf` is **uninitialized**: it could contain anything. It is your function who should fill that memory. However, you call `generate_hash` for that **uninitialized** content. The result could be any. If you want to get the user's input, then you need to implement `.write` callback, but that way you cannot return digest string to the user: you need to store this string somewhere, and return on following `.read` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your assumptions are correct. I have a .write callback that contains copy_from_user(ker_buf, buf, len) that is how I get buf variable to string in the first place. generate_hash (test_hash in the link) should assign hashed string digest to buf variable I think, what do you think ? Then I convert it so make it available to be able to read from userspace again. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: With `copy_from_user(ker_buf, buf, len)` you copy a string, written by a user, into `ker_buf`. But you call `generate_hash` for `buf`, not for `ker_buf` one. And please, include **all relevant code** into the question post, not just a single function which works with unspecified variables and calls other unspecified functions.

Comment: 1) is `buf` a pointer to user or kernel memory? (if user, generate_hash will fail, if kernel, copy_to_user will fail) 2) is `len` the right number of bytes to copy to user?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I added the relevant code and made necessary edit. buf is from userspace to kernelspace and ker_buf is vice versa.

Comment: Well, now it is time to take a look into the first [comment  of  dratenik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63742987/hashing-same-string-generates-different-results-in-kernel-module?noredirect=1#comment112718777_63742987): You allocate `digest_hd` array of size `SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE+2`, but write `SHA_DIGEST_SIZE * 2` characters into it (2 characters are written in each of SHA_DIGEST_SIZE iterations).

Comment: That's actually not a problem assuming SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE = SHA_DIGEST_SIZE * 2 (is it? that's also a relevant piece of code). But I see a problem with the differing meanings of the `len` variable. (is it the size of the input? is it the size of the resulting hash?)

Comment: SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE = SHA_DIGEST_SIZE * 2 so that shouldn't be the problem. If the checked the function from the link "static int test_hash(const unsigned char *data, unsigned int datalen, unsigned char *digest)" I think datalen corresponds to the len variable in the module. Does it have to be labeled identical ? I am sure we will figure this out :)

Comment: If we are to help you, please include **all relevant code**, that includes all variable definitions and macros used in the code and the body of `generate_hash` . Even if you're certain it's perfect you may easily have overlooked something.

Comment: And I think I need some bigger hammer for my point about `len`, it is an incoming argument for dev_read (number of bytes requested by user?) and that value is then handed to generate_hash as representing the number of bytes stored in ker_buf by dev_write (which is incorrect).

Comment: @dratenik do you think so that the issue is related to the len ? it's the length of user input as required by the generate_hash function in chip.c. Please see the edit

Comment: @servedc0ld it should be. But is it actually that? (and if it is, why do you use "length of user input" as the size of the resulting hash when copying back to user?) (it's _an_ issue, I don't claim it's **the** issue)

Comment: @dratenik as you proposed, I changed len to a large enough scalar value but got the same results

Comment: Now that you mention it, what _are_ the results? A more detailed description other than that they're not what you expected would make a fine addition to your question.

Comment: I write to the module "somestring" then I can read a corresponding hashed hexadecimal value that is correct in length but wrong in content. Array "digest" should be the binary representation of the input "somestring" and digest_hd should be the value converted to hex as it should be represented but as I mentioned content is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dev_write` has to remember how many bytes it stored and `dev_read` has to use that number instead of its `len` argument

```
static size_t ker_len = 0;
static ssize_t dev_read(struct file *filep,char *buf,size_t len,loff_t *off){
size_t i;
unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_SIZE];
unsigned char digest_hd[SHA_DIGEST_HD_SIZE+2];
int hash = generate_hash(ker_buf, ker_len, digest);

for (i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_SIZE; i++)
    sprintf(&digest_hd[i*2], "%02x", digest[i]);   

copy_to_user(buf,digest_hd,len);
return len;
}

static ssize_t dev_write(struct file *flip,const char *buf,size_t len,loff_t *off)
{  
copy_from_user(ker_buf,buf,len);
ker_buf[len]=0;
ker_len = len;
return len;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the exact value of buf read back from ker_buf. Input : 123456 Output : 123456, rather than hash of the input

Comment: @servedc0ld: oops, I missed one of your(?) edits in the question, fixing answer

Comment: it was a recommended edit, now it works as expected, thank you